# how to merge hash of hash with same keys in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, ruby-hash

I have a two 2nd level hash , and i have to merge both hashes

```
hash1 = {"brands"=>{"likes"=>["gucci", "ck", "armani", "heyo"], "dislikes"=>["lv", "tods", "pols"]}}

hash2 = {"brands"=>{"likes"=>["bampam","plot"], "dislikes"=>["pom", "ui"]}}
```

output should be

```
 hash1 = {"brands"=>{"likes"=>["gucci", "ck", "armani", "heyo","bampam","plot"], "dislikes"=>["lv", "tods", "pols","pom","ui"]}}
```

I have tried this code

```
hash1.merge!(hash2) { |k, o, n| o + n }
```

But this works for 1st level hash, not for 2nd level hash, hash inside hash

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag whats the problem if it's a duplicate question, there may be chance of other creative answer ,eh?

Comment: @Rajagopalan, this is not the place to debate SO policies. Note one can always add an answer to the earlier question.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Okay, thanks.